# why is the DataGrid MouseDoubleClick event fired when you double click on the scrollbar?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Why is the DataGrid MouseDoubleClick event fired when i double click on the scrollbar or on the header?

Is there any way to avoid this and fire the event only when i double clicked inside the datagrid.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Scrollbar and header are part of the grid but do not handle double click, so the event "bubbles" up to the grid.

The inelegant solution is to somewhat find out "what was clicked" by the mean of event source or mouse coordinates.

But you can also do something like that (untested):

```
<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
      <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="OnRowDoubleClicked"/>
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: this solution will works only when you going to override default DataGrid component -- in other word -- create own DataGrid component based on default one.

Answer (score 4):

You can check the details about the hit-point, inside the mouse click event -

```
DependencyObject dep = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;

// iteratively traverse the visual tree
while ((dep != null) &&
        !(dep is DataGridCell) &&
        !(dep is DataGridColumnHeader))
{
    dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
}

if (dep == null)
    return;

if (dep is DataGridColumnHeader)
{
    DataGridColumnHeader columnHeader = dep as DataGridColumnHeader;
    // do something
}

if (dep is DataGridCell)
{
    DataGridCell cell = dep as DataGridCell;
    // do something
}
```

https://blog.scottlogic.com/2008/12/02/wpf-datagrid-detecting-clicked-cell-and-row.html

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem and solved it with this:

```
DependencyObject src = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent((DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource);
if (!(src is Control) && src.GetType() != typeof(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Thumb))
{
    //your code
}
```

I've read this to get the idea: [How to detect double click on list view scroll bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056106/how-to-detect-double-click-on-list-view-scroll-bar)

I hope it'll help :)